# How to get parent node in a tree structure like this

Tags: c#, linq

How it would be possible to get a parent when tree structure is like this:

```
public class TreeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<TreeModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say we can't add a parent element item to this class (public TreeModel Parent { get; set; }).

## Edit

How to get element m22 (ID=22) parent m2 (ID=2) from the m1? I thought we could iterate through m1 and somehow return parent when condition is right.

```
var m1  = new TreeModel() { ID = 1  };
var m2  = new TreeModel() { ID = 2  };
var m21 = new TreeModel() { ID = 21 };
var m22 = new TreeModel() { ID = 22 };
var m3  = new TreeModel() { ID = 3  };

m1.Children.Add(m2);
m2.Children.Add(m21);
m2.Children.Add(m22);
m1.Children.Add(m3);

var parent = m1.GetParent(p => p.ID == 22); //<-- How?
```

Comment: Why are you need parent? How do you use this structure? If TreeModel doesn't have link to parent then you can't get parent. You'll have to add link of one kind or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<TreeModel> GetAllDescendants(IEnumerable<TreeModel> rootNodes)
{
    var descendants = rootNodes.SelectMany(_ => GetAllDescendants(_.Children));
    return rootNodes.Concat(descendants);
}


public static TreeModel GetParent(this TreeModel rootNode, Func<TreeModel, bool> childSelector)
{
    var allNodes = GetAllDescendants(new [] { rootNode });
    var parentsOfSelectedChildren = allNodes.Where(node => node.Children.Any(childSelector));

    return parentsOfSelectedChildren.Single();
}

m1.GetParent(_ => _.ID == 22);
```

1. Obtain a flat list of all nodes
2. Search this list for the node whose direct children contains m22

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
public class SaneTreeModel:  TreeModel
{
  public SaneTreeModel Parent { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code pattern. It simplifies the code because you don't have to explicitly add nodes to the children and each node knows who its parent is and who its children are. Also it is all type safe.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m1=new TreeModel() { ID=1 };
        var m2=new TreeModel(m1) { ID=2 };
        var m21=new TreeModel(m2) { ID=21 };
        var m22=new TreeModel(m2) { ID=22};
        var m3=new TreeModel(m1) { ID=3 };

        var item=m1.RecursiveFind((p) => p.ID==22);
        var parent=item.Parent;
        // parent.ID == 2
        var root=item.Root;
        // root.ID == 1;
    }
}

public class TreeModel : Tree<TreeModel>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public TreeModel() { }
    public TreeModel(TreeModel parent) : base(parent) { }
}

public class Tree<T> where T : Tree<T>
{
    protected Tree() : this(null) { }
    protected Tree(T parent)
    {
        Parent=parent;
        Children=new List<T>();
        if(parent!=null)
        {
            parent.Children.Add(this as T);
        }
    }
    public T Parent { get; set; }
    public List<T> Children { get; set; }
    public bool IsRoot { get { return Parent==null; } }
    public T Root { get { return IsRoot?this as T:Parent.Root; } }
    public T RecursiveFind(Predicate<T> check)
    {
        if(check(this as T)) return this as T;
        foreach(var item in Children)
        {
            var result=item.RecursiveFind(check);
            if(result!=null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When you derive from `Tree<T>`, you create custom tree structures that you design what the node class is (`TreeModel` here) and how to handle parents, children and siblings if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, with a child node like that you can't get its parent. Simply because there isn't any reference to it.

To get the parent of the node, you have to either add the parent field or save the reference in somewhere else (by a variable or something).

**EDIT**

@Zulis If you search from the root node, you can definitely find the node you want. But as I said, with just the child node you can't do that.

But I think you should avoid searching because that would be slow

Comment: I disagree - in the provided example m22 is a direct descendant of m1 so he (or she, idk) can absolutely find the parent node m2 (a direct child of m1) with a recursive search

Comment: But he can't do it with just the child node. See my update for more

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the downvote is yours, isn't it? If it is and you have nothing to say, please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by first finding the first element that satisfies the condition (ID == 22 in your example) and then finding the parent of this element. Not the best solution but maybe you will need them separately for something else.

```
public TreeModel GetParent(Func<TreeModel, bool> function)
{
    return GetParent(Where(function));
}

private TreeModel GetParent(TreeModel treeModel)
{
    if (Children == null) return null;

    if (Children.Contains(treeModel)) return this;

    foreach (TreeModel child in Children)
    {
        TreeModel result = child.GetParent(treeModel);
        if (result != null) 
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}

private TreeModel Where(Func<TreeModel, bool> function)
{
    if (Children == null) return null;

    foreach (TreeModel child in Children)
    {
        if (function(child))
            return child;

        TreeModel result = child.Where(function);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you put this code block in your TreeModel class, the example you provided will return m2